# Jersey: Trace classe when it inject http param

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, inject, hk2

I implemented my own ParamConverterProvider in order to use many AbstractParamConverter for parameters in my webservice.

for example I have two simple webservice like this :

```
@Path("/")
class MyWs {

    @PathParam("myobject")
    MyObject value;

    @GET
    method() {...}
}

@Path("/other")
class OtherWs {

    @PathParam("myobject")
    MyObject value;

    @GET
    method() {...}
}
```

I want to log (trace) the class name when the webservice binds/injects the http parameter.

e.g: "From MyWs.class binding parameter [myobject] with MyObject.class"

In fact, when it moves to following class:

```
public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
```

it losses the class name information.

Please advice me, if it possible to inject a parameter in my ParamConverterProvider or anything else to trace the class name.

Thanks